# A Javascript doesn't work to check all checkboxes with one in a GridView row

Tags: javascript, gridview

I'd like to ask you for help with the following issue. For some reason the below code doesn't work. When I'm clicking a last checkbox in a GridView row the checkbox is not checked and nothing happens with other checkboxes.

What I'm trying to achive is when a last checkbox is checked then all other checkboxes in a GridView row should be automaticaly checked and disabled. If I uncheck the last checkbox then all other checkboxes in a row should be not checked and enabled.

I'd appreciate your help.

Javascript code:

```
function SelectAll(chkBox) {
    var isChecked = chkBox.checked;
    var thisItem = chkBox.id;
    var items = chkBox.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].id != thisItem && items[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (isChecked) {
                items[i].checked = true;
                items[i].enabled = false;
            }
            else {
                items[i].checked = false;
                items[i].enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CountryAccessGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Country"
        BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#ece9d8" BorderStyle="solid">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="GridRow" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltRow" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div style="padding:10px;">
                There are no data
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Country_Descr")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phones" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox
                        ID="chkPhones"
                        runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lotus Notes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox
                        ID="chkLotus"
                        runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Relationship" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox
                        ID="chkRelationship"
                        runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country Administrator" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox 
                        ID="chkIsAdmin" 
                        runat="server"
                        OnClick="javascript:SelectAll(this);"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you post the resulting html? can't do much with templates...

Comment: Found a typo in the javascript code. Now it works fine :) @SparK, thank you.