# Unable to read checkbox in a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

From my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046385/a-javascript-doesnt-work-to-check-all-checkboxes-with-one-in-a-gridview-row#comment17715542_13046385)  I'm using a javascript to check some checkboxes which works fine. But then I have a button that puts some records in a database. Using the following code it doesn't matter whether a checkbox is checked or not it is always gives me false.

```
        bool first = true;
        bool _IsPhone = false;
        bool _IsLotus = false;
        bool _IsRelationship = false;
        bool _IsAdmin = false;
        string _Country;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in CountryAccessGrid.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ch = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPhones"));

            _Country = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblCountryShort")).Text;
            _IsPhone = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPhones")).Checked;
            _IsLotus = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkLotus")).Checked;
            _IsRelationship = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRelationship")).Checked;
            _IsAdmin = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkIsAdmin")).Checked;

            if (_IsPhone == true || _IsLotus == true || _IsRelationship == true || _IsRelationship == true || _IsAdmin == true)
            {
                cntr = cntr + 1;

                if (!first)
                {
                    insertaccess += " UNION ALL ";
                }
                insertaccess += " SELECT " + _UserID + ", '" + _Country + "', " + _IsPhone + ", " + _IsLotus + ", " + _IsRelationship + ", " + _IsAdmin;

                first = false;
            }
        }
```

How to get a state of a checkbox, please?

Comment: From where is this code, what is the DataSource and how/when do you DataBind it to the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to asnwer this question we have to know following:

- from where is this code
- what is the `DataSource`
- where/when do you `DataBind` it to the `GridView`?

But i assume that you always `DataBind` it in `Page_Load` even if it's a postback. That would override the values and prevents the events from being triggered.

So you have to use the [`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindGridView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you to use `RowDataBound event`

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         var ch = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPhones");
    }
  }

<asp:gridview id="GridView"  onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound" runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```